# how to create UI like below in HTML

Tags: html, css, email-templates

[image: add background like this]

```
.leftside {
padding: 16px;
background-color: #0E1E2B;
border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
```

}`

I made a design for a website page and I want to add the background above in the header using HTML and CSS. in this same background I also added it right-side, here I'm adding the CSS code that I tried. I can not understand how to create a background like this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `clip-path`. This site generate some figures. Site link: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this by using pseudo elements and the `border` CSS property.

Example of the theory behind how this works here: [How CSS triangles work](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)

**Codepen link:** https://codepen.io/thechewy/pen/eYVMLGM

```css
.leftside {
  width: 18rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

/** triangle **/

.leftside:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 10rem solid white;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftside"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you may try or start with:

```css
#shape {
  width: 200px;
  border-top: 120px solid #ec3504;
  border-left: 60px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="shape"></div>
```

Alternative options would be to use javascript library or even do in Html 5 canvas.